How to parse log from file to get SEVERITY and FACILITY from syslog-ng
I have a file in input : input.txt with logs message written in a specific format with dates, severity.. (i can modify this format if needed).
=> I want to parse this file with syslog-ng to send these logs on a server. I succeed to get date and the message but not severity and facility.
As a sumup i tried to simplify it with the following problem :
I have this file input.txt
user notice
authpriv err
daemon notice
auth info

And i want the same file in output, currently what i get is the following :
user notice
user notice
user notice
user notice

I tried many things with syslog-parser, csv-parser, flags(syslog-protocol) or templates but didn't succeed.
Here is a slight example of the interesting syslog-ng.conf :
source s_input { file("/home/***/test/syslog-ng/input.txt"); };
destination d_output{ file("/home/***/test/syslog-ng/output.txt" template("${FACILITY} ${LEVEL}\n")); };
log { source(s_input); parser {syslog-parser();}; destination(d_output); };

Is it possible to get these $FACILITY $LEVEL macro from syslog-ng? And how to do it if possible.
Thank you

It is difficult to understand what is asked here. If you literally "want the same file in output", that would be cp input.txt output.txt.  Furthermore, you say that your current output is missing severity, but it has notice, which is a severity level.

As said in introduction, i just simplified the problem with the blocking point. But the main goal is to send these logs to a server. This server will also receive logs from other clients.
The severity that i get is "notice" by default, but i would like to keep the initial severity. => So i would like "err" instead of "notice" when the case occurs.
